# ORA-00933 using case/when inside a select

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write this code into the toad, but it throws an ORA-00933 (SQL command not properly ended), just at the first WHEN.

I don't know exactly what happens. I've tried to follow the ORACLE docs, but with no success. Any help?

I let you the code written with toad.

```
select template.seq_temp, rules.fec_desde_serv, rules.seq_rec, rules.seq_agencia, rules.SEQ_TTOO, rules.COD_INTERFACE, pais.COD_PAIS, rules.cod_idioma
from re_t_vp_voucher_template template, re_t_vp_voucher_rules rules, re_t_vp_voucher_rules_pais pais, 
    case &tipser
        when 'TRF' then re_t_vp_voucher_rules_trf trf
        when 'ACC' then re_t_vp_voucher_rules_acc acct
        else re_t_vp_voucher_rules_otro otro
    end 
where template.seq_temp = rules.seq_temp
    and RULES.SEQ_RULE = PAIS.SEQ_RULE

group by template.seq_temp, rules.fec_desde_serv, rules.seq_rec, rules.seq_agencia, rules.SEQ_TTOO, rules.COD_INTERFACE, pais.COD_PAIS, rules.cod_idioma
order by template.seq_temp, rules.fec_desde_serv;
```

Comment: `&tipser` is not a valid identifier in SQL. In SQL*Plus this would be a variable. Does Toad support this as well?

Comment: It's the way parameters must be inserted in a query. When you press F9 to execute it, toad asks for a value for them. That's not the problem.

Comment: You have a random word n your first (and second) WHEN `re_t_vp_voucher_rules_trf trf`. Remove the second `trf`.

Comment: P.S. please use explicit joins (i.e. write JOIN) it makes your code clearer and it's easier to catch errors with joins that way.

Comment: trf is just an alias, that's not either the mistake... I'll try with joins, but I can't see why do I have to change the dependencies or relations to join... I mean don't understand why that should change the situatin, but I'll try it anyway. Thanks @Ben.

Comment: You can't alias the result of a WHEN clause... so it is the issue; you can only alias a column/table (i.e. an object). Joins won't change the situation; it's just cleaner. You're also missing an AND before the CASE statement in the WHERE clause as [Ankit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25759998/458741) has just (really sort of) pointed out.

Comment: In this line `when 'TRF' then and rules.seq_rule = trf.seq_rule` the `and` is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot use CASE construct in FROM clause.

So your SQL as highlighted below is incorrect.

```
from re_t_vp_voucher_template template, re_t_vp_voucher_rules rules, re_t_vp_voucher_rules_pais pais, 
    case &tipser
        when 'TRF' then re_t_vp_voucher_rules_trf trf
        when 'ACC' then re_t_vp_voucher_rules_acc acct
        else re_t_vp_voucher_rules_otro otro
    end 
where template.seq_temp = rules.seq_temp
```

The reason is that, you are trying to use dynamic table names in SQL, which is NOT allowed. You can't use dynamic table names in SQL unless you write dynamic SQL statements (i.e. build up the statement as a string in PL/SQL and then execute it using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or the DBMS_SQL package).

So rewrite the query to meet the SQL standards, or (ab)use dynamic sql.

> CASE is an expression, which works like IF-THEN-ELSE logic, and Oracle
>   uses short-circuit evaluation. so, it always needs a comparison
>   expression. Which you cannot have in FROM clause.

Comment: It's a substitution variable, which can be used for an object name (assuming your client supports them), so this is incorrect (plus misses the real error).

Comment: You have mistaken. If you see the real issue is with the case construct in the FROM clause which is not allowed in SQL.

And I did not understand your comment, is it for me, really? The SQL that I have highlighted is to show OP that where it is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Your where condition is wrong.:-

```
where template.seq_temp = rules.seq_temp
and RULES.SEQ_RULE = PAIS.SEQ_RULE
    case &tipser
        when 'TRF' then and rules.seq_rule = trf.seq_rule
        when 'ACC' then and rules.seq_rule = acct.seq_rule
        else and rules.seq_rule = otro.seq_rule
    end
```

Try to remove the 'and' keywords from there.

Comment: You really need an AND keyword in the WHERE clause... so this is wrong. It should go before the CASE...

Comment: Try to remove the and keywords from your case statements. Or add some cond. between them.

Comment: Forget the second case, the problem is inside the first case.

Comment: The first and foremost issue is that CASE cannot be used in FROM clause. As i mentioned it in my answer.